# Any word for battling of leaves in the wind?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any sound word to describe the battle against leaves in the windstorms?

Comment: Hi Hiba, welcome to English Language & Usage! Can you provide an example sentence of how you would use this word in a sentence, it will help provide context for anyone that attempts to answer your question.